# Code stucks at MX_USB_DEVICE_Init(); and gets fixed when connected to other side of the USB comm

Tags: usb, stm32

I use STM32F103C8Tx but USB communication does not work as it intends to. Sometimes codestuck at MX_USB_DEVICE_Init(); function.. More spesifically  it gets stuck at

USBx->BTABLE = BTABLE_ADDRESS;

line inside of MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

When I connect other side of the USB Communication, it gets fixed.

What might be the reason behind that? So do I need to connect USB device, or will it stuck in MX_USB_DEVICE_Init(); function?

Note: It is not related to interrupt priority.
Edit: Since the whole code is too long. Here is the part where it gets stuck: ( I use FREERTOS.)

```
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{

    /* init code for USB_DEVICE */
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
    //Set all variables to zero at the beginning
    int dischargeSOCLevel;
    socBattery1 = -1;
    socBattery2 = -1;
    dc1_done=0;
    dc2_done=0;
    started =0;
    dc1_count=0;
    dc2_count=0;
    previous_time=0;
    pre_error=0;
    error=0;
    derivative=0;
    //integral=0;
    temperatureBank2=0;
    temperatureBank1=0;
    realise=0;
    avarage_current=0;
    avarage_counter=0;
    I2C_transmit_fail_count=0;
    I2C_receive_fail_count=0;
     currentDischargerState=DS_INITIALIZING;
    osDelay(13000);
...
```

Here is the  CubeMX Settings for USB:

[image: CubeMX General View]

[image: CubeMX USB Window]

[image: CUbeMX USB_Device Window]

When I debug, Code stuck in this line:

```
  /*Set Btable Address*/
  USBx->BTABLE = BTABLE_ADDRESS;
```

I know this question is too general but I don't really know what is the problem or where should I explain in more depth. So if any further questions, please ask.

Comment: Well you could start by giving a minimal viable example. This isn't all that informative about what you are trying to do. My guess  would be: you are letting the STM32 be the host and as such wouldn't go further until a client is attached.

Comment: Yes, STM32 is the host. But sometimes without a client it does not get stuck in initialization, sometimes it gets stuck. Isn't it supposed to work without the client? Indeed I will not be able to transmit or receive a message, but at least it should not get stuck in the initialization process I believe.

Comment: Again the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is important, I just had to guess (correctly) that you are trying to be the host. We can't help you if we don't have enough context. Also if you add the correct bits of code, please format these using the code tags provided in the editor.

Comment: Edited. I don't know how to give more details. Or what might cause the problem, so it preventsme from explaining the problem deeply.

Comment: What is the other side to which you actually connect? I can't  think of a thing that needs to be connected to as being the host and needs CDC

Comment: Well the other side is PC. When I connect it to PC via USB it passes the line it stucked before.

Comment: So it is an USB client device. Do you call Init multiple times?

Comment: No, it gets stuck before I call it. I mean it gets stuck in initialization and I call the initialization only once. But actually in case of a voltage drop, MCU will reset itself. So Maybe voltage drop occurs and because of the reset it will init the USB again. Would it make it stuck though?